# How to programatically accomplish url authorization in iis7 for an application?

Tags: c#, iis, authorization

I created a ftp site "TestFtpSite" and an application with path "/LocalUser/demor". Here is the configuration in ApplicationHost.config.

```
<site name="TestFtpSite" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="TestFtpPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="F:\empty-ftp-folder" />
            </application>
            <application path="/LocalUser/demor" applicationPool="TestFtpPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="F:\HJ_STORAGE\demor" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="ftp" bindingInformation="*:21:" />
            </bindings>
            <ftpServer>
                <security>
                    <ssl controlChannelPolicy="SslAllow" dataChannelPolicy="SslAllow" />
                    <authentication>
                        <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    </authentication>
                </security>
                <userIsolation mode="IsolateAllDirectories">
                    <activeDirectory />
                </userIsolation>
            </ftpServer>
        </site>
```

After reading [understanding-iis-url-authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/understanding-iis-url-authorization), I found that we can add **location** tag in **ApplicationHost.config** file to secure an application. But I couldn't find any code snippet or api on how to add the **location** tag with authorization rule to the configuration file pragmatically.
I want to achieve below pragmatically using C#.

```
<location path="TestFtpsite/LocalUser/Bob"> 
    <system.ftpServer> 
        <security> 
            <authorization> 
                <clear />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="Bob" permissions="Read, Write"/>                  
            </authorization> 
        </security> 
    </system.ftpServer> 
</location>
```

--------------Update----------------------

Finally, I solved it inspired by [programmatically-unlocking-iis-configuration-sections-in-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717154/programmatically-unlocking-iis-configuration-sections-in-powershell)

This is my solution, hope it will help someone.

```
        // be sure to reference Microsoft.Web.Administration firstly
        ServerManager sm = new ServerManager();
        Configuration config= sm.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

        /*************************
         * Unlock the section
         * ***********************/
        ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("system.ftpServer/security/authorization", "TestFtpSite/LocalUser/demor");
        section.OverrideMode = OverrideMode.Allow;
        sm.CommitChanges(); 

        // Get a new instance of the configuration object
        config = sm.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
        section = config.GetSection("system.ftpServer/security/authorization", "TestFtpSite/LocalUser/demor");
        ConfigurationElementCollection authCollection = section.GetCollection();

        ConfigurationElement clearElement = authCollection.CreateElement("clear");
        authCollection.Add(clearElement);

        ConfigurationElement addElement =  authCollection.CreateElement("add");
        addElement.SetAttributeValue("accessType", "Allow");
        addElement.SetAttributeValue("users", "demor");
        addElement.SetAttributeValue("permissions", "Read, Write");
        authCollection.Add(addElement);

        sm.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Finally, I found the solution.  see [programmatically-unlocking-iis-configuration-sections-in-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717154/programmatically-unlocking-iis-configuration-sections-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Authorize attribute. The usage depends on the technology use are using but for MVC you would put it on the controller or action like this.

```
[Authorize(Users="Bob")]
public ActionResult LocalUser()
{
    . . .
}
```

Comment: I am using Server Manager in Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll  to manage my ftp site . If I added an application then the configuration file reflected the change. I  mean how to add the location tag with authorization rule to the configuration file pragmatically to secure my application with path "/TestFtpSite/LocalUser/Bob". Any idea?